Why Java CachedRowset.updateDate("date",null) and CachedRowset.updateNull("date") gets error?
This is my sample table in Apache Derby Database 16.1:
CREATE TABLE Projects
(
    PROJECT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1,
INCREMENT BY 1),
    PROJECT_TITLE VARCHAR(100),
    START_DATE DATE
)


INSERT INTO Projects(Project_Title, Start_Date)
Values ("Test Project 1000", '2023-01-15')

INSERT INTO Projects(Project_Title, Start_Date)
Values ("Test Project 2000", '2023-02-21')

This is how the CachedRowSet is created:
RowSetFactory myRowSetFactory;
CachedRowSet cached_RowSet;

myRowSetFactory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
cached_RowSet = myRowSetFactory.createCachedRowSet();
cached_RowSet.setUrl("DATABASE_URL");
cached_RowSet.setUsername("USERNAME");
cached_RowSet.setPassword("PASSWORD");
int [] keys = {1};
cached_RowSet.setKeyColumns(keys);
cached_RowSet.setCommand("Select * from Projects");
cached_RowSet.execute();

This is how updating the database is done:
cached_RowSet.absolute(1);
cached_RowSet.updateString("Project_Title","Project Title Update 1000");
cached_RowSet.updateDate("Start_Date", null);  // ---> gets error!!!
//or this one --->  cached_RowSet.updateNull("Start_Date"); ---> also gets error!!!
cached_RowSet.acceptChanges();

This will give error!
This is the error that I get:
java.sql.SQLDataException: 22005 : [0] DATE, [1] INTEGER
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:84)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:141)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Util.java:225)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Util.java:220)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(EmbedConnection.java:3208)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.newSQLException(ConnectionChild.java:153)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.dataTypeConversion(EmbedPreparedStatement.java:1714)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.setNull(EmbedPreparedStatement.java:345)
at java.sql.rowset/com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetWriter.updateOriginalRow(CachedRowSetWriter.java:752)
at java.sql.rowset/com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetWriter.writeData(CachedRowSetWriter.java:366)
at java.sql.rowset/com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.acceptChanges(CachedRowSetImpl.java:898)  ........ xxxxxxxxx

This is using OpenJDK 17.
However, if I use statement like:
UPDATE Projects SET Start_Date = null WHERE Project_ID = 1

it works. I think there is a bug in Java CachedRowSet. Please help.
Please help. I had posted this question more than one year ago already. Nobody can solve this.
Please help. Thanks.
i tried to set the date field to null using cachedrowset.updateDate("date",null) or cachedrowset.updateNull("date"). since the date field in question is nullable, i am expecting it to be set to null value. but cachedrowset always gives error.
as a work around i have to use the SQL Statement "UPDATE Projects SET Start_Date = null WHERE Project_ID = 1". This works but not the cachedrowset thing which i really want to do.
I think there is a bug in Java CachedRowSet. Please help.
Please help
